# React avoid re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

For a project, we want to have notifications visible throughout all views in the app.

The sidebar menu allows users to move between views, and is on the same level as the notification component and the websocket component [react-stomp](https://github.com/lahsivjar/react-stomp). The router is used to change the view on the next level depending on the selected menu item.

Our problem is that if a new message arrives, we need to pass it down to the view as props, and of course this triggers a re-render of the entire component.

Is there a way to avoid this rerender?

We would like to avoid redux, though we are aware it is a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, if props changes react will trigger re-render. If you want to avoid rendering a componenet you can use the hook `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`

Quoting React's documentation:

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

For further reading visit [their docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried experimenting with react lifecycle event hooks ?

Comment: Not that familiar, will look into them now!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`REACT CONTEXT`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API if you want to avoid using a state manager like Redux or MobX

Comment: but that will still cause re-render

Comment: yeah I know I was trying to come up with a solution on the other part of the question i.e. how to provide the data from top level component to other parts, but yeah like other suggested they could either use life cycle hooks or extend `PureComponent`